# Make Maven Surefire not redirect the tests stderr output

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I analyze JUnit tests using Strace. In order to do that properly, I log several JUnit events (beforeEach, afterEach, ...) using java.util.logging.Logger.
The Java logger, as well as Strace write both into stderr, which is as it should be, while the actual test results should output to stdout.
When I run the tests using Java directly, everything works as intended, but when I use maven surefire, the stdout outputs are correct, while the tests stderr outputs are automatically redirected to an .xml file in the surefire-reports folder and I end up having only the data from Strace in the stderr output.

Is there a way to tell Maven Surefire to not redirect the stderr?

This is my maven surefire configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                <useFile>true</useFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting [`<redirectTestOutputToFile>`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) explicitly to `false`. Maybe the default value of `false` is getting overriden somehow.